# Change URl without page refresh NEXT.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am developing a ecommerce store using `NEXT.JS` and `Redux`. So in product listing page, I have sorting select dropdown with `Price Low to High`, `Price High to Low` and `New Arrivals`. Upon selecting this option, I want to change the URL without page refresh and API call should occure. I have tried using below code, but it is not working and page is reloading.

```
function sortBy(value) {
    router.replace({
        pathname: '/products/'+slug,
        query: { sort: value }
    })

    dispatch(fetchproducts(slug, sort));
}
```

The above code just refresh the current page and appending `sort` param to URL.

So is it possible to do it without page refresh like in `Flipkart`.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

With the help of `shallow-routing` change of URL without doing a page reload is possible. It can be enabled by passing explicit option object as third argument to `Router.push`, i.e `{ shallow: true }`

From the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing)

> Shallow routing allows you to change the URL without running data fetching methods again, that includes `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps`, and `getInitialProps`.
>
> You'll receive the updated `pathname` and the `query` via the `router` object (added by `useRouter` or `withRouter`), without losing state.

For example, this how you would update the query param `sortBy` for pathname `/products` with the help of `shallow-routing`.

```
Router.push({
  pathname: '/products',
  query: { sortBy: 'price' }
}, 
undefined, { shallow: true }
)
```

**But there are a few caveats** It is not possible to do `shallow-routing` between different pages, it works only for same page URL changes. See the [caveat section](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing#caveats) for more details.

For example, you can update a query param for page `/product` page, but it won't be possible if you try to do `shallow-routing` from `/product` to `/product/[slug]` because they are two distinct pages.

```
// page will reload because shallow-routing not possible between the pages
Router.push('/product', '/product/some-product?sortBy=price', { shallow: true })
```

Comment: I just want to add `?sort=3` to URL. Current URL is `http://localhost:3000/products/dfhdf/sgsdg?sort=1`. But still the page is reloading. I have used `const router = useRouter()`.

Comment: Then you can use `router.push`. Pass the first argument and second argument as is and provide the third argument as on object with option shallow as true `{ shallow: true}`. Remember it will only work same page URL changes.

Comment: `router.push('/products/dfhdf?sort=1', '/products/dfhdf?sort=1', { shallow: true})`. Not working, URL is same. Just added `?sort=1`.

Comment: I suspect the `dfhdf` part is a route param for a dynamic route. And the page looks something like `pages/products/[slug].js` in file system. So you should be router.push should look something like this `router.push('/products/[slug]?sort=1', '/products/dfhdf?sort=1', { shallow: true}`

Comment: Yes. That did the trick. It is a dynamic route `[...slug].js`. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Hey @subashMahapatra, I tried to follow what you suggested above, but it didn't work unfortunately. Could you take a look at this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62858582/7186666

Comment: Same scenario using [...slug].js on page level - /page/[...slug].js. I'm not encountering any error but still, it reloads the page. So my router is like this `router.push('/[...slug]?sort=1', '/level1/level2?sort=1', { shallow: true}`

Comment: This does not reload the page anymore, but it it still resetting all state to the default values, which makes it unusable for most people I imagine

Answer (score 20):

Example:
you have a folder like: posts/[id].js and your url is like http://something.com/posts/123

You want to add a query param that will not refresh the page and your url will be like: http://something.com/posts/123?param=ok

all you need to do is:

```
const postId = 123;
const param = 'ok';
router.push(
    {
      pathname: `/posts/[id]`,
      query: {
        postId,
        param
      }
    },
    `/posts/${postId}?param=${param}`,
    {shallow: true}
);
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally found what was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me. It's easier than `useRouter` but fewer options. Gives me an anchor link which is what I needed. Read more in the [NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link)

My [category].js has a `fetch` call in a `useEffect` hook, and router picks up the URL parameters, makes the call, and populates the data. The page doesn't refresh.

```js
function createSortLink(sortBy) {

    const url = new URL('https://example.com/products/[category].js');
    url.searchParams.set('sortBy', sortBy);

    return (
        <Link 
          href={url}
          shallow={true}
          >
          {name}
        </Link>
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how do you set searchParams field on a string? I dont get how it works

Comment: @ColdDarkness Good point. It needs to be a URL object. I updated my answer. Thank you.