# Shallow routing using withRouter and custom server not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Using withRouter as a wrapper with custom server, shallow routing doesn't seem to be working.

I currently use this method to change the route:

```
this.props.router.push({
    pathname: currentPath,
    query: currentQuery,
});
```

router prop comes from using withRouter to wrap my class component.

And couldn't figure where to put the shallow flag. So I switched to the method mentioned in the docs:

```
this.props.router.push('/post/[pid]?hello=123', '/post/abc?hello=123', { shallow: true })
```

So I did that manually, but I started getting 404s.

```
http://localhost:3000/_next/static/development/pages/search/%5Btype%5D/%5Bcat%5D/%5Barea%5D.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

decoded:

```
"http://localhost:3000/_next/static/development/pages/search/[type]/[cat]/[area].js"
```

I tried using :type instead of [type] but it also didn't work.

This is how it's configured on the server:

```
    if ('/search/:type/:cat/:area' === route.path) {
        return app.render(req, res, route.page);
    }
```

Folder Structure:

```
/pages/search/index.js
```

I think this structure has something to do with the problem, since it's in the index.js and not just a plain file in the pages folder.

It should not reload the page while changing the route, that's the main thing I'm trying to accomplish.
I'm implementing SSR pagination, and I'm planning to use shallow routing to make page changes happen on the client instead of the server. Meaning achieve SSR on first load only, keep user in without refreshing.

I also tried this:

```
server.get('/search/:type/:cat/:area', (req, res) => {
         console.log("reached here...");   // this gets logged
        return app.render(
            req,
            res,
            '/search/[type]/[cat]/[area]',
            req.params
        );
});
```

But I'm getting 404s, the page is not there now!

This also didn't work:

```
   this.props.router.push(
        `/search/[type]/[cat]/[area]?${stringifyQs(currentQuery)}`,
        {
            pathname: currentPath,
            query: currentQuery,
        },
        { shallow: true }
    );
```

Comment: The `404` error might be the result because there is no  `pages/search/[type]/[cat]/[area].js` page in the file system. You have to export a React component in that file which will render the page for that route path. And sorry but I am having a hard time understanding what exactly you are trying to achieve with the shallow-routing.

Comment: Shallow routing in case of `this.props.router.push('/post/[pid]?hello=123', '/post/abc?hello=123', { shallow: true })` will only work when you are already on the path `/post/abc` and you are trying to update the URL path with the query `hello=123`.

Comment: @subashMahapatra I'll give you more details. I use SSR, the search page exist in the /pages/search/index.js

so the file you talk about won't be there unfortunately.

Comment: Anything else we could try to fix this issue? The parameters won't change, just the query.

Comment: Wait a sec, did you mean to update the URL something like this. `/search?type=some-type&cat=asdfsd&area=some-area` ?

Comment: Not exactly, the url will be like this: /search/type/cat/area. Every push changes the query params like page from 1 to 2, etc.

Comment: This path doesn't exist in the project, we dont have it: "http://localhost:3000/_next/static/development/pages/search/[type]/[cat]/[area].js"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217733/discussion-between-subashmahapatra-and-omar-dulaimi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

`server.js`

```js
server.get('/search/:type/:cat/:area', (req, res) => {
  return app.render(req, res, '/search', {
    ...req.params,
    ...req.query,
  });
});
```

`pages/search/index.js`

```js
props.router.push(
  '/search?type=foo&cat=bar&area=baz&counter=10',
  '/search/foo/bar/baz?counter=10',
  { shallow: true }
);
```

Linked issue from [GitHub](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/15091#issuecomment-658194957)