# How to dynamically change URL in a Next.js application without using <Link>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I know it's possible to dynamically change the URL without refreshing the page by using `<Link>`; however, is it possible to do so without `<Link>`? For context, I'm trying to change the URL dynamically on a page to another one if a variable changes its value from `false` to `true`. The variable's value isn't dependent on a button being clicked on, so that's why I don't want to use `<Link>`. At the moment, I'm using `window.top.location.href` inside of a `useEffect()`, which gets the job done — but it's very clunky since the entire page reloads. Does anyone know how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

The following is what I'm currently doing:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (status === true) {
    window.top.location.href='https://www.website.com'
  };
}, [status];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change URl without page refresh NEXT.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845014/change-url-without-page-refresh-next-js)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't @EmmaKoskinen. The solution suggested there involves shallow-routing, but that only works for same page URL changes (_e.g._, /fruits -> /fruits?sort=3). I'm trying to go from one page to an entirely different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. All I needed to do was swap out the line with `window.top.location.href` to `router.push()`. The following is the updated code that works as intended:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (status === true) {
    router.push('https://www.website.com')
  };
}, [status];
```