Next.JS : Update URL without the page reloading
I'm building a chat application using Next.js and I'm facing an issue with rendering selected chat messages in a specific (div) while ensuring that the URL reflects the selected chat.
// MY APP LAYOUT
export default function MyAppLayout({ props }) {
  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-12 h-screen w-screen bg-[#F7FAFC] dark:bg-black overflow-hidden">
      {/* Sidebar */}
      <div className="hidden sm:inline sm:col-span-1 relative">
        {/* Sidebar content */}
      </div>

      {/* Div 2 */}
      <div className={`col-span-12 sm:inline sm:col-span-4 px-4 border-l-[0.5px] border-gray-300 dark:border-gray-800 h-screen`}>
        {props.children} {/* Renders different content based on the route all chats , profile page etc*/}
      </div>

      {/* Div 3 */}
      <div className={`col-span-12 sm:inline sm:col-span-7 h-screen dark:bg-black`}>
        {/* Should display selected chat messages with URL reflecting the selection */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


The sidebar (div-1) and mid column (div-2) should always be visible.
The message panel (div-3) should be visible only when a chat is selected.
When a chat is selected, the URL should update to reflect the selected chat without navigating to a different page.
The chat messages should be rendered in the message panel (div-3) based on the selected chat.

use router.replace function https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#userouter

i tried but not working in my case -
router.replace(/chats/u/${secondUserInfoOnChat.username},{ scroll: false })
it is redirecting me to another page but i don't want to navigate to a different page

what version of nextjs do you use ?

currently i am using 14.2.3

its strange because replace shouldnt navigate to different page and just replace address that do you have in browser. can you provide some example to better understanding?

i am doing like this

const handleChatClick = () => {
setRecipientUser(secondUserInfoOnChat)
router.replace(/chats/u/${secondUserInfoOnChat.username}, { scroll: false })
};
i am rendering column-3 div only when the chat is selected
and when i click on chat column 3 will be render but it i navigate me to different page

please provide some https://codesandbox.io/ example

check - https://codesandbox.io/p/live/e2e3f07f-aeb6-4dbd-a879-634f952806d7

its not running

@IgorZinchenko: What makes you say router.replace shouldn't navigate to a different page ? The documentation says: "Perform a client-side navigation to the provided route without adding a new entry into the browser’s history stack". So it should navigate.

try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845014/change-url-without-page-refresh-next-js
